# Raspberry Pi4 Camera supported=0

Tags: pi-4, picamera

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and I am trying to connect the board with Raspberry Pi camera module. I made sure that the camera is connect correctly to the insertion slot. And the camera is enabled through both command line `sudo raspy-config` and the desktop Raspberry Pi configuration. However, when I do `vcgencmd get_camera` I see supported=0 detected=0. I don't understand how come the board doesn't support the camera?

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you using Raspberry Pi OS Buster or Bullseye? Is that an official Pi camera - which model?

Comment: I am using RASPBERRY PI OS FULL 32-BIT downloaded from the  rspi imager. This is where I get my camera https://abra-electronics.com/robotics-embedded-electronics/raspberry-pi-en-3/cameras-en-2/pi-camera-720p-5mp-mobile-camera-cmos-based-for-raspberry-b-pi-2-and-pi-3.html

Comment: The camera looks like a 3rd party product - similar to the "official" 5MP camera but not quite. So hard to say what sort of quality they are. Otherwise just double check the connector into the Pi socket really has the ribbon contacts around the right way.